# Fastest way to delete a TStrings item without sort

Tags: delphi, duplicates, tstringlist

I plan to develop software that does not use the sorted property with TStrings class and remove duplicate items. What is the best way to do this performance wise? Thanks for your expertise as always or direction to follow. Hope I am clear with the question, basically a list of text where duplicate lines are removed yet remain unsorted. The file pertains to IRC info and it can be somewhat large in size. I think the log last I checked was around 1.2 megs or so.

TIA for your words of wisdom

Comment: Consider using Dictionary<>.

Comment: Is there an example in house or TDictionary basic example to do this without sorting? I have never used the class.

Comment: Typically dictionaries don't accept duplicates. So you don't really need an example. Just populate it and duplicates are removed on the way. However the rtl dictionary is unordered so you won't retain the order of the lines. Some dictionaries do maintain order. The spring4d is the example that I know of an ordered dictionary.

Comment: A TStrings is an array in data structure terms. Removing duplicates in an unsorted array is an O(N^2) operation. That's going to be too slow I suspect. So a data structure like an ordered array would deal with that performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid duplicates, so keep dictionary (here it is used as set) with strings already in the list.

Example:

```
uses System.Generics.Collections;

var
  MyDict: TDictionary<String, Integer>;
  s: string;
  sl: TStringList;
  strs: array of string;
begin
  strs := ['aa', 'bb', 'aa', 'dd'];
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    MyDict := TDictionary<String, Integer>.Create;
    try
      for s in strs do
         if Mydict.TryAdd(s, 1) then
            sl.Add(s);
      Memo1.Lines.Assign(sl);
    finally
      MyDict.Free;
    end;
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Thank you both for guidance, I appreicate it. @MBo I think your approach is also interesting but for whatever reason will not compile properly when using Delphi 10. The compiler complains about the "if not (s in MyDict)" line. Do you know why this would happen? Exact error is [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(32): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

Comment: I've changed example. Perhaps you cannot set `strs` in your Delphi by this way, but it is not a problem - just provide string sequence

Comment: Thanks, your code works now but you are using a predetermined array which is hardcoded. If I were to open a file for example how would this easily translate to such an array? Each string would be 1 element as in your example but dynamic. Thanks

Comment: Loop code does not depend on string source - you can read file with TFile.ReadAllText and walk through its lines or use another method (TStringList.LoadFromFile, old fashion ReadLn etc)

Comment: No `try..finally`s? (I know you would use them in real code, MBo, but I'm afraid that SO answers without `try..finally`s will increase the number of real apps lacking those safeguards because people simply learn and copy from SO answers.)

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand This code is far for real usage, so I omitted try/finally. OK, added now

Comment: @mbo sorry just realised that. I think I'd still use the ordered dictionary in serious code but this is a perfectly good solution.

Comment: @WayOfTheWright Is your question about removing duplicates, or reading a text file line by line? Questions here should be narrow in focus.

Comment: @Mbo Use `TryAdd`(https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary.TryAdd) to half the number of dictionary find operations, e.g. `if MyDict.TryAdd(s, 1)) then sl.Add(s);`

Comment: Storing an `Integer ` in this case doesn't make much sense, since the stored words are not being counted. I would store a `Boolean` instead. Too bad Delphi doesn't have an equivalent of C++'s `std::set`, then no value would be needed at all. I'm sure there is a 3rd party `Set`-like class for Delphi somewhere. Or, not too hard to make such a class using similar logic as  TDictionary` uses internally.